# How to change a specific numpy array inside a arrays of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, linear-algebra

I'm writing a program but I'm finding dificulties to update a numpy array.
The code:

```
print("p: " + str(pontoP))
print("d: " + str(deslocamento))
novoP = np.array([0,0,0])
novoP =  pontoP + deslocamento
pontos[i] = novoP
print("p+d: " + str(pontos[i]))
```

The output:

```
p: [0.         1.         0.33333333]
d: [ 0. -1.  0.]
p+d: [0 0 0]
```

**pontoP**, **novoP** and **deslocamento**  are 1D numpy arrays (length 3), and **pontos** is a 2D numpy array (size 8 x 3).

The line **novoP =  pontoP + deslocamento** is working: the arrays are being summed element-wise.  However, **pontos[i] = novoP** is failing to update the 2D array **pontos**.
What can I do? The desired result is to replace the ith array of **pontos** with the contents of **novoP**.

Comment: what is `pontos.dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj. some integer, dollars to donuts

Comment: don't try to put float values in an int dtype array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hpauli , I found that the issue was the type of numpy array. It was an `int` and when I tried to put a float in it, the float was being rounded.